# Create a reduced term-term adjacency-matrix from a bigger one using a list of given words

Tags: r, text-mining, adjacency-matrix

After analyzing a large amount of scientific papers, I have ended with a term-term adjacency-matrix of about **32000 terms** like the following sample:

```
              Terms
Terms          abart abb abbieg abbiegelicht abblend abblendlicht abbrech abbrems abdeck abend
  abart            4   1      0            0       0            1       0       0      2     0
  abb              1   6      0            4       2            4       0       0      3     2
  abbieg           0   0      4            3       3            2       0       0      3     3
  abbiegelicht     0   4      3           12       7            8       1       1      5     5
  abblend          0   2      3            7      12            6       1       1      7    10
  abblendlicht     1   4      2            8       6           20       3       3     10    11
  abbrech          0   0      0            1       1            3       4       2      2     1
  abbrems          0   0      0            1       1            3       2       5      3     2
  abdeck           2   3      3            5       7           10       2       3     17     9
  abend            0   2      3            5      10           11       1       2      9    1
```

I have been given a list of words which usually come together. The frequency of this adjacent appearances is also very high:

```
wordsToStudy <- c("dog","cat","cow","horse","donkey","goat", "elephant")
```

I have been given the task to analyze the degree of relationship between those words, but also to discover which other terms (initially not given) also have an high "adjacency-index" with the given terms.

For example, I assume that the word "mouse" will appear in those other terms, as although "cat" probably has the biggest association with mouse, "dog" (because of both being pets) and "elephant" (because of its panic to mice), probably appear frequently next to each other.

I imagine that the biggest handicap is to find terms which not only have a strong association with the given words, but also have any kind of association between each other. If mouse is accepted as a possible new term, and "bull" also (because its association with "cow"), probably mouse and bull doesn't have any kind of relationship. This wouldn't be desired, but of course acceptable.

The perfect approach would be to be able to manually determine the ammount of terms (lets say 50, 100, 200 terms...) to be included in the reduced term-term adjacency-matrix. I have thought that the final output should be adjacency graph like the following picture:

[image: Extracted from: http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/social-network-analysis]

I have really basic knowledge of statistics and maybe what I am looking for is known in this science with a particular term. Maybe you know a package able to do it, as I don't know how to do it manually.

My actual code is:

```
# Packages ----------------------------------------------------------------
require(RWeka)
require(tau)
require(tm)
require(tm.plugin.webmining)
require(wordcloud)
require(igraph)

#specify where is the directory of the files.
folderdir="C:/texts"
#load the corpus.
corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(folderdir, encoding = "UTF-8"), readerControl=list(reader=readPlain,language="de"))
#cleanse the corpus.
ds0.1g <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
ds1.1g <- tm_map(ds0.1g, content_transformer(removeWords), stopwords("german"))
ds2.1g <- tm_map(ds1.1g, stripWhitespace)
ds3.1g <- tm_map(ds2.1g, removePunctuation)
ds4.1g <- tm_map(ds3.1g, stemDocument)
ds4.1g <- tm_map(ds4.1g, removeNumbers)
#create matrixes.
tdm.1g <- TermDocumentMatrix(ds4.1g)
dtm.1g <- DocumentTermMatrix(ds4.1g)
#reduce the sparcity.
tdm89.1g <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.1g, 0.89)
tdm9.1g  <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.1g, 0.9)
tdm91.1g <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.1g, 0.91)
tdm92.1g <- removeSparseTerms(tdm.1g, 0.92)

tdm2.1g <- tdm92.1g

# Creates a Boolean matrix (counts # docs w/terms, not raw # terms)
tdm3.1g <- inspect(tdm2.1g)
tdm3.1g[tdm3.1g>=1] <- 1

# Transform into a term-term adjacency matrix
> termMatrix.1gram <- tdm3.1g %*% t(tdm3.1g)

# build a graph from the above matrix
g <- graph.adjacency(termMatrix.1gram, weighted=T, mode = "undirected")
# remove loops
g <- simplify(g)
# set labels and degrees of vertices
V(g)$label <- V(g)$name
V(g)$degree <- degree(g)

# set seed to make the layout reproducible
set.seed(3952)
layout1 <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)

# set label size of vertices based on their degrees and width and transparency of edges based on their weights
V(g)$label.cex <- 2.2 * V(g)$degree / max(V(g)$degree)+ .2
V(g)$label.color <- rgb(0, 0, .2, .8)
V(g)$frame.color <- NA
egam <- (log(E(g)$weight)+.4) / max(log(E(g)$weight)+.4)
E(g)$color <- rgb(.5, .5, 0, egam)
E(g)$width <- egam
# plot the graph in layout1
plot(g, layout=layout1)
```

Comment: @Augustin, did you ever figure out a solution to this?